# Migrating Spring boot 1.5 to 2.x unable to start app

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm new to Spring boot and trying to migrate an existing application from 1.5 to 2.0.
 I went through the migration guide and found out that including the preoperties-migrator as dependency in my parent pom will point out the changes to be done in order to migrate.Hence i added the below dependency in my **pom.xml**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-properties-migrator</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.4.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Once i added the below dependency, app startup failed with below error.

> "message":"Application startup
>   failed","logger_name":"org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication","thread_name":"main","level":"ERROR","level_value":40000,"stack_trace":"java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org/springframework/boot/env/OriginTrackedMapPropertySource\n\tat
>   org.springframework.boot.context.properties.migrator.PropertiesMigrationListener.onApplicationPreparedEvent(PropertiesMigrationListener.java:67)\n\tat
>   org.springframework.boot.context.properties.migrator.PropertiesMigrationListener.onApplicationEvent(PropertiesMigrationListener.java:57)\n\tat
>   org.springframework.boot.context.properties.migrator.PropertiesMigrationListener.onApplicationEvent(PropertiesMigrationListener.java:44)\n\tat
>   org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:172)\n\tat
>   org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:165)\n\tat
>   org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:139)\n\tat
>   org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:122)\n\tat
>   org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.contextLoaded(EventPublishingRunListener.java:91)\n\tat
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.contextLoaded(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:66)\n\tat
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.prepareContext(SpringApplication.java:356)\n\tat
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:301)\n\tat
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1118)\n\tat
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1107)\n\tat
>   com.move.aws.eai.inventory.common.app.BaseApplication.run(BaseApplication.java:140)\n\tat
>   com.move.aws.eai.inventory.bulk.Application.main(Application.java:10)\nCaused
>   by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   org.springframework.boot.env.OriginTrackedMapPropertySource\n\tat
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)\n\tat
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)\n\tat
>   sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)\n\tat
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)\n\t... 15 common
>   frames omitted\n"}

Can anybody point out whats wrong.

**pom.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <parent>
    <groupId>com.move.aws.eai.inventory</groupId>
    <artifactId>aurora</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.20-SNAPSHOT</version>
  </parent>
  <groupId>com.move.aws.eai.inventory.aurora</groupId>
  <artifactId>bulk</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>Inventory and Waitlist Bulk API</name>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.move.aws.eai.inventory.aurora</groupId>
      <artifactId>common</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
      <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-sts</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
      <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-s3</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-hateoas</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-dbcp2</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Features toggling -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.togglz</groupId>
      <artifactId>togglz-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.togglz</groupId>
      <artifactId>togglz-console</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Testing -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
      <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
      <artifactId>powermock-module-junit4</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
      <artifactId>powermock-api-mockito2</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.github.stefanbirkner</groupId>
      <artifactId>system-rules</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.mybatis.spring.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>mybatis-spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <finalName>inventory-bulk</finalName>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <!-- Package as an executable jar -->
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>repackage</goal>
              <goal>build-info</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
          <executable>true</executable>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
      </snapshots>
      <id>central</id>
      <name>EnterpriseSystems-inventory-maven</name>
      <url>https://artifactory.moveaws.com/artifactory/EnterpriseSystems-inventory-maven</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
      <snapshots />
      <id>snapshots</id>
      <name>EnterpriseSystems-inventory-maven</name>
      <url>https://artifactory.moveaws.com/artifactory/EnterpriseSystems-inventory-maven</url>
    </repository>
  </repositories>
</project>
```

Comment: Looks to me that you have incompatible versions of some of Spring's dependencies. I suspect you are not using Spring's BOM, or that you have some explicit versions in your parent.

Comment: If i post my parent pom.xml, would you be able to point out whats wrong? @BoristheSpider

Comment: As the error is somewhere in `org.springframework.boot.context.properties`, I would guess that it's something to do with your usage of Togglz. From [the documentation](https://www.togglz.org/documentation/spring-boot-starter.html) it looks like `2.6.1.Final` is required for Boot 2.x. Are you using the right versions?

Comment: could you add your parent pom definition? <parent>
    <groupId>com.move.aws.eai.inventory</groupId>
    <artifactId>aurora</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.20-SNAPSHOT</version>
  </parent>

Answer (score 2):

It was a silly error.

I changed the parent pom.xml to use the latest Spring boot version.

Comment: I cannot upgrade to the latest spring boot, as we share the session with different microservices and those were using spring boot 1.5.9

Comment: @KrishLakshmanan not sure, but isnt that the change in your parent pom.xml reflect in ur microservices pom as well ?